# Send command from PC application to Jailbroken iphone

Tags: c#, iphone, jailbreak, tweak

I am making an simple application on PC by C# to send command to jailbroken iphone (exp: open app, get list application installed on iphone..e.t.c..) but I do not know how to send to iphone, searching google but can not find a thing to do this. Anyone know how to send command to iphone please point me out or some documents to learn about this.
Thank you.

Comment: If you've jailbroken your device you should have an SSH server running on the device. Get Putty and login on your device through SSH (port 22), default username is "root" with password "alpine" (could depend on the jailbreak you've used). You can make yourself familiar with how to start process etc. there, and you can also establish an SSH connection through C# libraries.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt so how can i send command to jailbroken iphone without login by SSH but by C#. Can you share me which library on C# help me to do this without ssh on iphone?, as i read on some comments on google, they said that i must have/code a tweak on iphone to listen to command from c# and use that tweak to trigger command on iphone

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective-C or native programming on iOS at all. However, I've succesfully deployed an application to my cracked iPad using "Codename One", which allows you to write applications (AND the UI) in Java and Eclipse for free, even on Windows. You can write an arbitrary application that way. I have no info on writing a native tweak and have it listen on a port and accept connections.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt well we are dicussing about how to sent command to ios from C# but not creating a hybrid application. I can create a hybrid application with onsen ui and angularjs, you can take a look at onsen-ui :D. it is good i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion the best way to go is using SSH, here's the steps

### On the Jailbroken device (Skip this steps if you already have an ssh server installed and running)

1. Download the SSH server from Cydia
2. Take note of your device's IP address
3. Default username: `root` and password: `alpine` **Remember to change that!, also i would recommend creating another user for your app**

### In your application

1. Download and install the SSH.NET library from NuGET [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/)
2. Implement your appropriate methods to connect,disconnect and send commands, se those examples:

   ```
   using (var client = new SshClient("phoneIp", "phoneUsername", "phonePassword")) {
       client.Connect();
       //Open the Facebook app and show your profile
       client.RunCommand("open fb://profile");
       //Alternative method using `uiopen`
       client.RunCommand("uiopen fb://profile");

       //Read device network info (install network-cmds first)
       Console.WriteLine(client.RunCommand("ifconfig"));

       //List all apps installed via Cydia
       Console.WriteLine(client.RunCommand("dpkg –list"));

       //List all apps that are installed from iTunes/Appstore
       Console.WriteLine(client.RunCommand("cat /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"));
       client.Disconnect();
   }
   ```

I haven't tested this code of course, and I have no Jailbroken iOS device, but this should put you on the right path at least!

Comment: How can i send command hiddenly (not showing on iphone screen ) by ssh sir?

Comment: What do you mean by not showing on the phone screen?  All the commands are invisible except for the one that launch apps

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a daemon on your jailbroken iDevice. It will contain a TCP server, which accepts connections from your PC and translates them into your commands. After that commands will be executed by your daemon and you have to write code to process each type of command.

Comment: so i must create a tweak to execute command take from TCP server send on PC Application?, do you have any demo that i can take a look at it? thank at first :D

Answer (score 0):

Another one easy solution would be to use Cycript in conjunction with SSH.
If Cycript is installed on the jailbroken phone and a SSH server is running, you could write some scripts and upload it to the phone.
By running them, it would output relevant informations to the standard output.

You would still have to do some very basic reversing stuff to know what you want to to display (i.e. asking the right SpringBoard controller to have the desired information)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you share more about Cycript or a demo to take a look at it :). Further more, what is " some very basic reversing stuff " you are talking about, do you have any more information about this, more clearly i mean :)